# Using an alias in a script to display computer name

Tags: powershell

I am attempting the following code, but I can't get the computer name to display once I open a powershell session.  Can anyone help?

```
New-Alias myhome get-myhome
function get-myhome
{
$computername = $wshnetwork.computername
$wshshell = new-object -comobject "wscript.shell"
$wshshell.$env:COMPUTERNAME
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but here's an example of how to make a box pop up with your computer's name...

```
Function Get-MyHome {
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("$env:COMPUTERNAME",0,"This Computer's Name",0x1)
}

New-Alias myhome Get-MyHome
myhome
```

Edit: Even though this makes no sense, this is how you could echo the computer name...

```
Function Get-MyHome {
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("$env:COMPUTERNAME")
}

New-Alias myhome Get-MyHome
myhome
```

I think the powershell commandlet `Write-Output $env:COMPUTERNAME` does what you're really after.

Comment: How can I display the result at the command prompt instead of using a popup?

Comment: `Write-Output $env:COMPUTER` will echo your computer name to the command line

Comment: Thank you it was a great help.  One question though, is  Write-Output the only method to send the output to the screen?

Comment: There's also `Write-Host` and `Write-Console` I believe, but each behaves a bit differently. There's a nice discussion of the differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline

Comment: @SteveB if this is the answer you were looking for, don't be afraid to accept it as an answer! Otherwise, please let us know what isn't working!

Comment: Yes, it worked well.  However, do you have to have the alias AFTER the function script?  I was thinking that the alias had to be there before the function would operate correctly.